# Receive, edit and update a value in Parse.com

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to update a value in parse, this is my code to receive the value:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"currentUploads")
            query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:post.objID)
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (restaurants: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let objects = restaurants as? [PFObject] {
                        var firstObject = objects[0]
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                            self.currentVotes = firstObject["reportedCount"] as! String
                            println(self.currentVotes)
                        })

                    }
                }
            }
```

In the output, it gives me the number 5 from the `println`, and that is correct. But now I want to increase the number by 1 so it goes to 6, and update that in parse.com

How can I do this?

Comment: add one to it and save it.....

Comment: @ChrisL this can be done much more efficiently by using `PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: objectId:)` and then calling `incrementKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the objectId, you can do this without querying first by using pointers.

Try the following

```
// Create a pointer to an object of class currentUploads with post.objID
let currentUpload = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "currentUploads", objectId: post.objID)

// Increment the key
currentUpload.incrementKey("reportedCount")    

// Save
currentUpload.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        // The object has been incremented
    } else {
        // There was a problem, check error.description
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I made it work also, but in my way i had to use 2066 characters and 36 lines of code :) Anyways, thank you!